# A less smutty cryptic crossword (#33)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

First grid I've done without auto-fill, though I did have to resort to a word finder. Next month's will be all my own work!

[image: Grid33]

```
Across
1   Make pastry for Spooner to serve caviar (4,3,3,5)  
9   Don't choose me: after the first of November I'll be in extreme confinement (3,2)  
10  Don't ignore the day Poe got drunk (3,4,2)  
11  Make chips faster: put King Edward in top half of oven (150C) with acceptable cover (9)  
12  Consecutive passes a first for Maradona (5)  
13  Call back to get a measure of modem performance (4)  
15  Where there's a shell-like hearing the exact words (8)  
18  Listen to Aussie rocker (8)  
19  Bridge from Thames to the West, high and fair (4)  
22  High country is GE-free at first (5)  
24  Acceptable truce on vacant, marginal ground (9)  
26  Outside dilapidated cabin is where Samoans stay fit (9)  
27  Leaders of imperial delegation rendered impotent since Elba (5)  
28  Roger owes Kate a French movie (3,5,7)  

Down    
1   Rome, lacking conclusion from senate, is without direction (6)  
2   Opposing direction of a ruthless, wicked denomination (9)  
3   It's pushed up by one bar, keeping fit after work (5)  
4   To the average American girl, perhaps insinuates highest price (3,6)  
5   Austrian economist finds agreement in part of China (5)  
6   Moving Dalek with cord (like a rope) attached to head (9)  
7   Nude gymnastics after university are inappropriate (5)  
8   Bird droppings picked up in Devonshire park (6)  
14  Poem about the setter is in a couple of small books (9)  
16  Letters from Democrat rep on emancipation could give you syphilis (9)  
17  Interference in programme (mostly dance) may hold up gala (5,4)  
20  Bottom line, is Penny up for it? (6)  
21  It's a party on a boat for the secret police (6)  
23  Tax the church, stupid! (5)  
24  Biro at the ready, recorded volume of boxes (5)  
25  One of those quarterback Johnnies, loser of Superbowl I, who fought in Angola (5)
```

Comment: (The answer shouldn't be put in the question. I have added the image to the answer; thank you VERY much for providing it!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### COMPLETED!

> [image]

*(Solution grid graciously provided by OP.)*

#### Across

1   Make pastry for Spooner to serve caviar (4,3,3,5)

> **ROLL OUT THE DOUGH**   Dole out the roe (*spooner*)

9   Don't choose me: after the first of November I'll be in extreme confinement (3,2)

> **NOT IT**   N_ + OT(I)T — *OTT* is a British abbrev for Over The Top
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan, @M Oehm for explaining OTT*

10  Don't ignore the day Poe got drunk (3,4,2)

> **PAY HEED TO**   (THE DAY POE)*

11  Make chips faster: put King Edward in top half of oven (150C) with acceptable cover (9)

> **OVERCLOCK**   OV_(ER)+CL + O(C)K

12  Consecutive passes a first for Maradona (5)

> **DIEGO**   *ddef.* ; DIE and GO are ways to "pass", consecutively — Diego Maradona
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan for construction*

13  Call back to get a measure of modem performance (4)

> **BAUD**   A inside DUB<

15  Where there's a shell-like hearing the exact words (8)

> **LITTORAL**   Literal (*hom.*)

18  Listen to Aussie rocker (8)

> **OSBOURNE**   Ozzie (*hom.*)

19  Bridge from Thames to the West, high and fair (4)

> **KOPU**   (UP+OK)< — the *[Kopu Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopu_Bridge)* in Thames, NZ (which even goes west from Thames)!
>          *— thanks @M Oehm for the correct word*

22  High country is GE-free at first (5)

> **RIDGE**   RID + GE

24  Acceptable truce on vacant, marginal ground (9)

> **CROMULENT**   (TRUCE ON M(argina)L)* — "vacant" MARGINAL; "ground" is anagrind
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan*

26  Outside dilapidated cabin is where Samoans stay fit (9)

> **FANCIABLE**   FA(CABIN*)LE — *def.* is "fit"; a *fale* is a house or building in Samoa

27  Leaders of imperial delegation rendered impotent since Elba (5)

> **IDRIS**   I_ D_ R_ I_ S_ — Idris Elba, actor

28  Roger owes Kate a French movie (3,5,7)

> **THE FORCE AWAKENS**   (OWES KATE A FRENCH)* — "Roger" is anagrind (a UK thing?)
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan*

#### Down

1   Rome, lacking conclusion from senate, is without direction (6)

> **RANDOM**    ROME lacking (senat)E → “R and OM” (*reverse wordplay*)

2   Opposing direction of a ruthless, wicked denomination (9)

> **LUTHERANS**   (A RUTHLESS)* and change S→N

3   It's pushed up by one bar, keeping fit after work (5)

> **OPTIC**   "fit" (TIC) after "work" (OP).  — *def.*: [optic: British trademark:
>
>                A device fastened to the neck of an inverted bottle for measuring out spirits.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/optic)
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan for answer, @M Oehm for construction*

4   To the average American girl, perhaps insinuates highest price (3,6)

> **TOP DOLLAR**   TO (DOLL) PAR — American girl (DOLL) insinuated into...

5   Austrian economist finds agreement in part of China (5)

> **HAYEK**   H(AYE)K — [Friedrich Hayek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Hayek), Austrian economist

6   Moving Dalek with cord (like a rope) attached to head (9)

> **DREADLOCK**   (DALEK CORD)*

7   Nude gymnastics after university are inappropriate (5)

> **UNDUE**   U + (NUDE)*

8   Bird droppings picked up in Devonshire park (6)

> **HOOPOE**   H(POO<)OE — *def.* is "Bird"; *Hoe Park* is a place in Plymouth, in Devon

14  Poem about the setter is in a couple of small books (9)

> **DUODECIMO**   DU(ODE + C + IM)O — "about" is *c.* (circa); "setter is" is *I'm*.
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan for CIM construction*

16  Letters from Democrat rep on emancipation could give you syphillis (9)

> **TREPONEMA**   Democra**t rep on ema**ncipation

17  Interference in programme (mostly dance) may hold up gala (5,4)

> **APPLE TREE**   APP(LET)REE is "programme" (APP) + "mostly dance" (REE-l)
>                — *Let* is, as in tennis, interference on a play, and
>                  Gala is a variety of apple
>          *— thanks @M Oehm for the word guess*

20  Bottom line, is Penny up for it? (6)

> **PROFIT**   P + FOR< + IT

21  It's a party on a boat for the secret police (6)

> **STASIS**   (ITSA)* "on a boat" (inside SS) — *def.* from [Stasi](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stasi?s=t), formerly secret police in E.Germany
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan*

23  Tax the church, stupid! (5)

> **DUNCE**   DUN + C.E.

24  Biro at the ready, recorded volume of boxes (5)

> **CUBIC**   *ddef.*; CUE BIC (*hom.*)
>          *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan*

25  One of those quarterback Johnnies, loser of Superbowl I, who fought in Angola (5)

> **UNITA**   UNITAS loses (first of) S(uperbowl) — [Johnny Unitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Unitas), a quarterback
>         *— thanks @Gareth McCaughan for the word guess*

Comment: 6d is ~LOCK not ~KNOT. 14dn CIM is c. (about) + I'm. I think 1d is "R and OM". 9a is NOT IT (N + I in OTT). 24 is CUBIC (BIC after homophone of CUE). 28a is THE FORCE AWAKENS ("owes Kate a French" is getting rogered). 24a is CROMULENT (TRUCE ON + M(argina)L, "ground"). 21d is, I suppose, STASI'S (ITSA* in SS). 12a is DIE + GO, both meaning "pass".

Comment: I bet 25a is UNITA but I don't understand the wordplay yet. I bet 3d is OPTIC but I don't understand the wordplay yet (and I'm not confident I understand the definition either). Still puzzled by 17s and 19a.

Comment: OPTIC is TIC (a nervous fiit) after OP (work).

Comment: 17 must be APPLE TREE ("may hold up Gala", a sort of apple), but I can't work out the wordplay.

Comment: @MOehm Ah yes, should have seen "fit" (though to me a tic and a fit are quite different things, as different as a slap and a fight or a shelf and a library). Still not 100% convinced by the definition part either.

Comment: @MOehm 3d: An optic works by placing the rim of the glass into the foot and pushing up to get a measure of spirits. Hence it is "pushed up by one barkeeping"

Comment: @RupertMorrish I don't get the "and". Where'd it come from, or is this one of those reverse-wordplay things that seem wrong to me? hehe

Comment: Is it reverse wordplay? If it is, I should probably have signposted it. ROME without E is R and OM.

Comment: 17D I had intended Interference = LET as in "without let or hindrance". The tennis interpretation works just as well, I think.